# How do we add features like did you mean this and suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, kibana

I am making a search engine using elasticsearch in which i want some features like 'Did you mean this' and 'Suggestions' like google does.
My index contains a document like this:
{
"نام" : "قرآنی انسائیکلوپیڈیا",
"موضوع" : " کائنات کی بامقصد تخلیق سے استدلال",
"عربی میں" : " الاستدلال بخلق الكون الهادف",
" Topic " : "The argument from creating the cosmos with a purpose (i.e. the argument from teleology)",
"حوالہ" : "أَلَمْ تَرَ أَنَّ اللّهَ خَلَقَ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضَ بِالْحَقِّ إِن يَشَأْ يُذْهِبْكُمْ وَيَأْتِ بِخَلْقٍ جَدِيدٍ ",
"ترجمہ" : "(اے سننے والے!) کیا تو نے نہیں دیکھا کہ بیشک اللہ نے آسمانوں اور زمین کو حق (پر مبنی حکمت) کے ساتھ پیدا فرمایا۔ اگر وہ چاہے (تو) تمہیں نیست و نابود فرما دے اور (تمہاری جگہ) نئی مخلوق لے آئے",
"باب" : "(إِبْرَاهِيْم, 14 : 19)",

}
This is just a single document i have large amount of documents like this one with same fields, so how can i add such features on a index containing document like this one!
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement the "Did you mean" feature, you can do it with [Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html). First, you have to make a new analyzer that uses nGrams (shingles). Then, set the analyzer to the field. Finally, use the query :

```
{
"suggest": {
    "text": " (your text here) ",
    "phrase_suggestion": {
        "phrase": {
            "field": "test.trigram",
            "max_errors": 0.95,
            "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
            "gram_size": 2,
            "size": 3,
              "direct_generator" : [ {
      "field" : "test.trigram",
      "suggest_mode" : "popular",
                "min_word_length": 1
    }]
        }
    }
}
```

you can read more about the options above in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html).

**NOTE**:  the (test.trigram) is :

test = your field,

trigram = your analyzer